# getting Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Learning react by coding, i'm getting this error 'Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.' this kind of error is usually fixable using useEffect, but because it is in this function that dispatching should happen, i dont know how to put it in useEffect.

my graph is working fine but when i want to dispatch i get that error.
Simply what i am returning in those functions i want to dispatch it also. Any advice ? if needed some information ask me. English is not my mother language so could be mistakes

my code:

```js
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
 const visualGraph = useSelector((state: ) =>
 state.Articlesgraph
  );

 const filteredGraphData = data && {
links: filteredGraphData.links.map((l) => {
  return {
    id: l.id,
  };
}),
nodes: filteredGraphData?.nodes.map((n) => {
  return {
    id: n.id,
  };
}),
  };


 const kk = () => {
    if (currentCam) {
      dispatch(ChangeGraphData(filteredGraphData));
    }

    return filteredGraphData;
  };

  const pp = () => {
    if (currentCam) {
      dispatch(ChangeGraphData(visualGraph));
    }

    return visualGraph;
  };


 <Graph
       
          data={filteredGraphData ? kk() : pp()}
         
        />
```

Comment: data={filteredGraphData ? kk() : pp()} ..... I think this line of code is making it run infinitly

Comment: My guess is that calling `kk` or `pp` updates `filteredGraphData`, which causes another re-render, and another call, and so on. There is code missing though, so I'm not sure: `filteredGraphData` is not defined anywher.

Comment: @Halcyon that part of my code was in the beginning like this           data={filteredGraphData ? filteredGraphData : visualGraph} and that works fine, but i want to dispatch during those so i changed it into function, is it right way ?

Comment: I kind of doubt that's your code, since `dispatch`, `ChangeGraphData`, `filteredGraphData`, `visualGraph` and `currentCam` are all name errors here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to call `kk` or `pp` every render. Maybe use a memo?

```
const hasData = !!filteredGraphData;
const data = React.useMemo(() => hasData ? kk() : pp(), [ hasData ]);

return  <Graph data={data} />;
```

The dependency on `hasData` (instead of `filteredGraphData`) is hopefully going to break your infinite loop.

Comment: that did not work even without dispatches, because in the beginning if filteredGraphData does not have data then it should 'visualGraph', so with your code im getting new errors even without dispatch

Comment: Post more of your code then, it's incomplete.

Comment: my graph works with this 'data({filteredGraphData ? filteredGraphData : visualGraph})',  i simply want to dispatch 'filteredGraphData' when filteredGraphData is true and when its not true then dispatch 'visualGraph', i think my question is simple ?

Comment: How are `visualGraph` and `filteredGraphData` defined? Without knowing how they're defined it's not clear to me how this should work.

Comment: added more info, visualGraph comes from redux and has {links:[{}],nodes:[{}]},  and 'data' comes from useEffect where i have setData, i cant provide more, is this clearer ?